# How to LAY/SHORT SELL multiple mutually exclusive outcomes in sequential events?

Tags: asset-allocation, risk-management

(n.b. Still not sure if this is the right place, but it was suggested by [@SRKX](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/467/srkx))

How would I calculate the percentage of my wealth to invest when **LAYING/SHORT SELLING** multiple mutually exclusive outcomes, using the kelly criterion?

Single exclusive outcomes for backing and laying I can do. Multiple mutually exclusive outcomes for backing I can do, but is there a specific calculation needed for laying multiple mutually exclusive outcomes?

There are already plenty of calculators that can do this regarding backing, but I can't seem to find nor calculate how to do this when it comes to laying?

I'd very much appreciate some direction. Thanks.

p.s. Here are some informative links. [Mutually exclusive events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_exclusive_events), and the [Kelly criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion).